# django rest framework, how to restrict the list of data a user can see?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose you want to show

- list of all blogs
- list of blogs created by a user

How do I implement them in django-rest-framework?

Do I make two viewsets?

Do I make two get_querysets() somehow?

Or two permissions class?

- Edit:

you want to show all blogs in a `recent` tab.
you want to show a user's blog in his `profile` page.
you want to show popular blogs in a `popular` tab.

There could many more list of blogs...

Comment: You should have two viewsets. Other options are not logical.

Comment: It depends on what are the requirement of showing one or the other. Maybe some usecase would be nice?

Comment: @ArunGhosh: two viewsets mean two url endpoints for list of a model?

Comment: @timop: added the use cases.

Comment: @eugene other option is to pass parameter to a single endpoint override get_queryset()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you'd like to just filter the queryset based on some given parameters. You should look at the django-filter and DRF filtering options. They might be what you really need. [Filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering)

> .../blogs/?owner=1

This will give you all blogs that have "owner" field equal to user with id==1

Another option is to use @list_route decorator inside your viewset like this:

```
@list_route
def popular(self, request)
   .... # Do stuff
   return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This will add a blogs route to your viewset and return whatever you tell it to return.
So going to '../blogs/popular/' will return 'data'

Comment: What exactly does 'popular' mean? Is it a value of a field or something that's calculated based on some params or something else?

Comment: well I thought ../popular_blogs/ might be better than ../blogs/?mode=popular

Comment: Changed my answer a little bit. Not sure which one is a better choice for you exactly